# Azure API Management Developer Portal - Create Client Id and Secret

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-api-management

From Azure API Management developer portal, Can we create client id and secret automatically while each user creates application?

Basically i need to set up my AD tenant/B2C Tenant and while application creation happens from API Manangement development portal, Development portal should automatically/programmatically call to my configured AD tenant/B2C tenant and should create Application inside AD/B2C, the created application's client id and secret should be written.

Is this feature supported in Azure APIM developer portal or please suggest best away to achieve inside APIM developer portal.

Thanks in advance.

Vetrivel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note as informed in [MSDN thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c9b94630-f916-4223-8b9e-caa0a1c84c8d/azure-api-management-developer-portal-create-client-id-and-secret?forum=azureapimgmt), as of now you may not be able to do it directly through Azure API Management. You can go ahead to log a feedback request here - http://aka.ms/apimwish.

For now, you can create separate application that would call both API Management API and AD API to setup required applications.